# Recommendation for 3rd Party .NET Serial Port Class/Component

Tags: .net, vb.net, serial-port

I am looking for a serial port component for .NET that overcomes the issues with the built-in Serial Port component related to sudden unplugging of USB-to-RS232 adapters, and suspension of the computer while the port is open.  (Untrappable errors occurring after the the device is unplugged or the computer comes back after being suspended.)

I have been using [Richard Grier's solution](http://home.comcast.net/~hardandsoftware/enhanced_serial_port_object_for.htm), but I still have problems when resuming from suspend.

Is there a 3rd party component that you would recommend?  I have tried several, and each have their shortcomings.  Ideally I'd like a drop-in replacement for the standard serial port, but I'll take whatever I can get.

(Note:  I apologize if you find this post a bit vague.  This question is targeted to those familiar with my problem... it is a very common issue.)

Thank you for your time.

**Edit:** It turns out that upgrading to .NET 4 and using the serial class works fine on XP, but does *not* work on Windows 7.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this issue with sudden unplugging of USB-to-RS232 adapters? I'm working on a project right now using .NET's built-in serial port components and we make heavy use of USB-to-RS232 adapters.

Comment: This post describes it best:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/0e4894cd-76db-4101-8cfc-7b7f13c1489a/

Comment: More: http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework/topic53568.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would be helpful to post *which* solutions you've tried (no sense in someone recommending something that you've already ruled out), I can recommend the [CommStudio](http://www.commstudio.com/commstudio) component.

While it's a bit pricey, it's a great component and has done well with a few high-throughput (relatively speaking, of course), highly-bidirectional applications that I've worked on, and it's never had an issue with unexpected device removal.

Comment: I didn't post which solutions I've tried because I didn't want to lead anyone.  Perhaps if several people had the same suggestion of something I've already tried, I'd go back and give it another shot.  Thank you for your suggestion, I'm checking it out now!

Comment: In the end, CommStudio Express was the *only* thing that worked reliably every time (including the fix in .NET 4.0 in the list of things that was tried).

Answer (score 2):

By [popular demand](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/140018/serialport-crashes-after-disconnect-of-usb-com-port), this was addressed in .NET 4.0.  There are two critical changes in the internal SerialStream and EventRunner classes.  The SerialStream.Dispose(bool) method avoids touching the serial port when the Windows API returns an access denied error, indicating that the port disappeared.  This will prevent the Dispose() method and the finalizer from crashing.

The EventRunner.CallEvents() method avoids throwing an uncatchable exception if an attempt to clear a serial port error fails.  Which would happen when the emulator is yanked out of the slot while it is in use.

---

The fundamental recommendation remains the same however, SerialPort will favor an exception whenever the device driver misbehaves and not let your program plod on without any diagnostic at all.  Drivers for USB emulators almost all misbehave when you unplug the USB connector while the serial port is in use.  You **must** use the "Safely Remove Hardware" tray icon.  Using this icon is required for any kind of device that does not natively support Plug & Play.  Like a serial port.

Comment: Cool! Looks like I will need to upgrade, but I think this will be the most straightforward solution. Thanks.

Comment: It turns out that everything works great in .NET 4 for XP, but I still get the exact same issues in Windows 7!  Any thoughts?